# UICollectionView - List of UICollectionViewCell to be returned in cellForItemAt

Tags: ios

I am making a menu, where I know the cells upfront. Therefore I create each cell `UICollectionViewCell()` in code. That use to work in `UITableView`, but in `UICollectionView` it gives error in `cellForItemAt`:

> does not have a reuseIdentifier - cells must be retrieved by calling
>   -`dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:forIndexPath:`'

Ok, so when I create each `UICollectionViewCell`(Custom super cell). It wants cell identifier, no problem. But I also wants `IndexPath`.

So the question is; how can I create `UICollectionViewCell` upfront?

Hope you can understand.

Answer (score 1):

> Collection view requires that you always dequeue views, rather than
>   create them explicitly in your code. There are two methods for
>   dequeueing views.
>
> - Use the 
>     `dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier:for:)`
>     to get a cell for an item in the collection view.
> - Use the 
>     `dequeueReusableSupplementaryView(ofKind:withReuseIdentifier:for:)`
>     method to get a supplementary view requested by the layout object.
>
> Before you call either of these methods, you must tell the collection
>   view how to create the corresponding view if one does not already
>   exist. For this, you must register either a class or a nib file with
>   the collection view. For example, when registering cells, you use the 
>   `register(_:forCellWithReuseIdentifier:)`  or 
>   `register(_:forCellWithReuseIdentifier:)`  method. As part of the
>   registration process, you specify the reuse identifier that identifies
>   the purpose of the view. This is the same string you use when
>   dequeueing the view later.

In delegate method `cellForItem(at:)` you need to dequeue cell by passing your reuse identifer and indexpath to method `dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier:for:)`, the returned object will be your cell.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    // reference to your cell
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath)
    return cell
}
```

If you are using stroyboards you need to set reuse identifier here 
[image]

and pass it to `dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier:for:)` method

[Here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/CollectionViewPGforIOS/CollectionViewBasics/CollectionViewBasics.html) you can find more information how to use collection views.